# what is wrong with this program/code?

Tags: java, oop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Checkdate {

    private static Scanner mon;

    public Checkdate(String x) {
        if (x == "feb") {
            System.out.println("lol");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("rofl");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String g;
        mon = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter string");
        g = mon.next();
        final Checkdate che = new Checkdate(g);
    }

}
```

this is just a simple program..even if i enter feb it shows rofl..i cant figure out whats wrong please help...

Comment: It doesn't do what you want, but since we have no idea what that is, or how it differs from that, can't be of much help.

Comment: You have to use if(x.equals("feb"))... it's the first error i can see